# BFF layer implimenttion using .net core web api for oth mobile & desktop?

Tags: microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi I want to develop Bff layer/ API Gateway's for both mobile & desktop as per below diagram.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icJ8Y.png)

I have already created API Gateway for desktop using ocelot . But i am confusing what type of code we need to write for mobile api gateway.

Comment: You can also use ocelot for the mobile API gateway. It doesn't make any difference. As I see you followed the architecture used by eshopOnContainers in which ocelot has been used for all the BFF gateways.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.